# Php stdClass Object to html list

Tags: php

Anyone know how to do this?

I have the code below stored in a variable and would like to echo it in different ways, such as:

- sum of values by country
- sum of values by city
- sum of values by state

Something like:

country-a: 220
country-b: 80
country-c: 70

state-a: 220
state-b: 80
state-c: 70

city-a: 220
city-b: 80
city-c: 70

```
 stdClass Object
(
    [city-a, state-a, country-a] => 100
    [city-a, state-a, country-a] => 120
    [city-b, state-b, country-b] => 80
    [city-c, state-c, country-c] => 70

)
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: reformatting he incoming data would make this a lot easier, what's the data source?

Comment: Structure is so inappropriate I would feel dirty giving an answer.

Comment: @Dagon: Data source is from Facebook's Graph API - Insights - page_fans_city. developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights (read insights permission needed - you can have look at on the FB API explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: could you give me the json code you're getting from the api?

Comment: Hi @JohannesStaehlin Here is the JSON code I get from the API

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "SOMEID/insights/page_fans_city/lifetime", 
      "name": "page_fans_city", 
      "period": "lifetime", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "Wattens, Tirol, Austria": 160, 
            "Imst, Tirol, Austria": 123, 
            "Zirl, Tirol, Austria": 117,
          }, 
          "end_time": ""
        }
      ], 
      "title": "", 
      "description": ""
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "", 
    "next": ""
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if you don't understand the code or need help with other functions.
I also shorted the json code. You could probably implement more functions to the class and create a nive FB-stats-interface for yourself.

//EDIT:
ok, I created a small API-interface for you. It contains one include file, an example of the usage and 2 example-json-files. Please name the files as followed and put them all in the same folder.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Your title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

<?php
//include files
include 'Stats.php';

//create an object of Stats
$stats = new Stats();

//parse any number of json files
$stats->parseJson("json1.txt");
$stats->parseJson("json2.txt");

//call the functions

print "<h1>var_dump of the data</h1>";

print '<pre>' . print_r($stats->getList(), true) . '</pre>';
print "<h1>By Country</h1>";
print "Austria:".$stats->getSumByCountry("Austria")."<br />";
print "Germany:".$stats->getSumByCountry("Germany")."<br />";
print "USA:".$stats->getSumByCountry("USA")."<br />";

print "<h1>By State</h1>";
print "Tirol:".$stats->getSumByState("Tirol")."<br />";
print "Bayern:".$stats->getSumByState("Bayern")."<br />";
print "Massachusetts:".$stats->getSumByState("Massachusetts")."<br />";

print "<h1>By City</h1>";
print "Austria:".$stats->getSumByCity("Imst")."<br />";
print "Berlin:".$stats->getSumByCity("Berlin")."<br />";
print "Los Angeles:".$stats->getSumByCity("Los Angeles")."<br />";




?>
</body>
</html>
```

Stats.php:

```
<?php
class Stats{
    private $cities;

    public function addCity($city){
        $this->cities[]=$city;
    }


    public function parseJson($jsonFile){
        $jsonData = file_get_contents($jsonFile);
        if($jsonData == null || $jsonData==""){
            die("Error: failed to load $jsonFile");
        }

        $object = json_decode($jsonData);
        //naviagte through the object to the data we want to have
        $data = $object->data;
        $temp_item = $data[0];
        $temp_value = $temp_item->values;
        $temp_item2 = $temp_value[0];
        $value = $temp_item2->value;

        //now create an entity of City for each entry and put it in the list of this class
        foreach ($value as  $key=> $item){
            $placeArray = explode(",",$key);
            $city = trim($placeArray[0]);
            $state = trim($placeArray[1]);
            $country = trim($placeArray[2]);
            $sum = $item;
            $this->addCity(new City($sum, $city, $state, $country));
        }
    }

    public function getSumByCity($name){
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($this->cities as $city){
            if(strcmp($city->name,$name) == 0){
                $sum += $city->sum;
            }
        }
        return $sum;
    }

    public function getSumByState($state){
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($this->cities as $city){
            echo "";
            if(strcmp($city->state,$state) == 0){
                $sum += $city->sum;
            }
        }
        return $sum;
    }
    public function getSumByCountry($country){
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($this->cities as $city){
            if(strcmp($city->country,$country) == 0){
                $sum += $city->sum;
            }
        }
        return $sum;
    }

    public function getList(){
        return $this->cities;
    }
}

class City{
    public $sum, $name, $state, $country;
    function __Construct($sum, $name, $state, $country){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->sum = $sum;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->country = $country;
    }
}
?>
```

json1.txt

```
{"data":[
    {"id":"SOMEID/insights/page_fans_city/lifetime",
     "name":"page_fans_city",
     "period":"lifetime",
     "values":[
        {"value":
            {"Wattens, Tirol, Austria":160,
             "Imst, Tirol, Austria":123,
             "Zirl, Tirol, Austria":117},
         "end_time":""}],
     "title":"",
     "description":""}],
 "paging":
    {"previous":"",
     "next":""}
}
```

json2.txt:

```
{"data":[
    {"id":"SOMEID/insights/page_fans_city/lifetime",
     "name":"page_fans_city",
     "period":"lifetime",
     "values":[
        {"value":
            {"Boston, Massachusetts, USA":199,
             "Los Angeles, California, USA":55},
         "end_time":""}],
     "title":"",
     "description":""}],
 "paging":
    {"previous":"",
     "next":""}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a mil @Johannes but unfortunately I can't get it to work. All I do is file_get_contents(PATH TO JSON DATA) and then put it into the json_decode(). Also, would it be possible to have it automatically grouped together so that I could run that code for different JSON inputs (different counrries, cities, etc.). Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it! PS. The error I get is: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: the error is because the array is not properly filled. If you only do file_get_contents(http://path to the whole json), of course you have to navigate from the the top node no the country/city data ;)
My code wasn't ment to be an exact copy & paste. And you can reuse the code for multiple json inputs! Please try: $json->file_get_contents(PATH TO JSON DATA) $nodeX = $json->NodeX .... $jsonDate -> $Node_OF_COUNTRIES.
Or wait 10h until I'm home from the office ;)

Comment: Hi @Johannes, thanks for that but now I'm totally confused :( Sorry, but as you can probably tell - I'm a newbie to PHP. Could you please help me implement it?